# Enum class and template

Tags: templates, c++11, enums

I have some templated class

```
template<typename ProgramBufferAttr>
struct CanvasDataBase{
   enum class DrawType {Brush, Attr, AttrInst};
}
```

In that class I have enum class. Now I want to use that enum. Is there any way to address that enum without specializing template (and without adding default typename ). Like this:

```
CanvasDataBase::DrawType::Brush
```

I can of course, move enum out of class. But...

Comment: Not that you have a struct, not a class, so the text is somewhat inconsistent.

Comment: @LaszloPapp In C++, a class is introduced using the keyword `class` (default access control is private) or the keyword `struct` (default access control is public). But in both cases it's a class in the C++ terminology.

Comment: @Angew: a struct is a struct, a class is a class. A struct is not equal to a class in the "C++ terminology". You are free to back your claim with the standard text. They have different traits (the access is not the only one that you mentioned though). It is confusing not to use the proper term.

Comment: @LaszloPapp according to the standard, `struct` and `class` keywords are  `class-key`s.

Comment: @nurettin: Please provide standard text that class and struct are the same and you can use the term interchangably for any of them. There are differences between them for a reason. Using them interchangably is effectively confusing. Please lower the confusion if I may ask.

Comment: Read chapter 9 `[class]`. "A class is a type. ... class-specifier:
class-head { member-specification_opt } ... class-head:
class-key *other nonterminals follow* ... class-key: class | struct | union"

Comment: And most importantly [class.access]§3: "Members of a class defined with the keyword `class` are `private` by default. Members of a class defined with the keywords `struct` or `union` are `public` by default."

Comment: @Angew: That does not seem to write that at all they are both the same. I actually suggest to read that chapter further. It must be explaining the differences between them.

Comment: @Angew: yes, exactly, so please stick to the right term to explain what features the code is actually representing.

Comment: @LaszloPapp Did you read the [class.access] quote? "Members of a **class** defined with the keywords `struct` or `union` are `public` by default." (emph mine). So it is a "class." The C++ standard only uses the word (not keyword) struct in the context of "standard-layout struct," which is a special kind of class.

Comment: @Angew: I really do not understand why you are still arguing. Using consistent names would be a clear benefit without drawback. I am afraid you are just arguing for the sake of arguing.

Comment: @LaszloPapp What you have difficulty realizing is that the question is completely unrelated to the differences between class and struct. You can specify the type with any of the class-keys.

Comment: @nurettin: no, what you have difficulty with is realizing that you are arguing for keeping inconsistent terms around in the question rather than improving the question itself. This site is about qualified questions and answers, and that is why many contributors work on it in their free time. Being consistent with terms when two terms represent two different features is fundamental.

Comment: @LaszloPapp I am not arguing for the sake of arguing. You said that the OP "has a struct, not a class." All I said was that in C++, they are both called "class."

Comment: @LaszloPapp I find asking about a class and declaring it as struct pretty consistent as long as the question isn't about their differences.

Comment: @Angew: Of course a struct is a class, but that does not make it consistent rather than using class-class, struct-struct. Sigh, I rarely have this hard time to get minor improvements into a question without any drawback. Anyway, -1 from my side, and leaving this unproductive discussion.

Comment: @LaszloPapp good luck with the madness and being the only contributor around.

Comment: @LaszloPapp Seriously? Did you just downvote a question because a 3rd party disagreed with your comment?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the enumeration is independent of the template parameter, you could create a non-template base class defining the enumeration and derive the class template from that base class:

```
struct CanvasDataDef {
  enum class DrawType { Brush, Attr, AttrInst };
};

template <typename ProgramBufferAttr>
struct CanvasDataBase : CanvasDataDef {
  //...
};
```

Then you can access the enumerators either as `CanvasDataDef::DrawType::Brush` or as `CanvasDataBase<ConcreteType>::DrawType::Brush`.

Note that this will actually change the semantics from the original version. In the original case, `CanvasDataBase<TypeA>::DrawType` and `CanvasDataBase<TypeB>::DrawType` are two distinct types and they cannot be assigned to each other. The base class will make them all compatible. This might or might not match what you want.

Comment: I think this is the same, as to store DrawType separately. Even without inheritance. Because in the end - CanvasDataBase<ConcreteType>::DrawType::Brush. And if we use base class - this is the same as store them separately.

Comment: @tower120: yeah, and eventually I think it is even more complex than storing separately due to the inheritance.

Comment: Sorry Angew, but want I want - is just simplify semantics. I think I'll stay with separate enum class . Sorry for spent time. Just want to know is it possible to do something with this.

Comment: @tower120: btw, Bjarne explicitly writes this in his new C++11 book that it should be avoided to put much non-templated logic into a template class, so I think having it separately is reasonable respectively. I will try to quote him during the evening if I do not forget to pick up the book.